# How to read HASH(0x1fcb970) using perl?

Tags: api, perl, hash, response

I'm really lost with this, how can I read this response form an API `HASH(0x1fcb970)` using perl.

```
my @info= $connection->fetchrow();
```

When I try to print the data:

```
print @info
```

is when I get the HASH.

Comment: If that's a string you are printing (or a content of a variable), then that is a hash reference.  So you need to dereference it, `my %h = %{$href};` (and in this case you may omit the curlies) if in a variable, or save it into a variable form wherever it comes and then dereference. Then you'll have a hash (an associative array, a dictionary) with key-value pairs etc

Comment: With your edit it appears that your `@info` has one element which is the hash reference; so it'd be `my %h = %{$info[0]};`, for example.

Comment: `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \@info`

Comment: Sorry made a mistake typing the question, it is "info" "info"

Comment: @Pedro The mistake is typing your code in. Always copy/paste code, and make sure it is *exactly* as in your own code. Otherwise, you are just wasting people's time thinking about the wrong things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is a hash reference but is being treated as a string. When you stringify a reference, you get something like "HASH(0x1fcb970)" instead of what you intended or expected. You see numbers that look like they may be a memory address, but those aren't useful to you.

You might start by inspecting what you got:

```
use Data::Dumper;

print Dumper( \@info );
```

If you see what you expect there, then it's on your side to treat the reference properly.

If it's an error on the API side. Open a ticket with them and have them fix it.

---

There was a major newspaper that had this happen to them in 1990s, as I recalled. All of their headlines were "HASH(0x...)" for a couple of hours. :)